# Terraform provider's resources not available in other tf files

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm just starting with terraform and I just don't grasp some of the basics.
I have two problems

I have a `main.tf` file where I initialise Terraform, declare 2 providers for Azure and Kubernetes, and define two modules.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
provider "kubernetes" {
    host                   =  module.cluster.host
    client_certificate     =  module.cluster.client_certificate
    client_key             =  module.cluster.client_key
    cluster_ca_certificate =  module.cluster.cluster_ca_certificate
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
module "cluster" {
  source = "./modules/cluster"
  location = var.location
  kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version
  ssh_key = var.ssh_key
  
}
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  
}
```

then in `modules/cluster/cluster.tf` I setup the resource group and the cluster.
when I define a new resource all azure and `kubernetes` providers modules are available.

I'm trying to add two new resources `azurem_public_ip` and an `azurem_lb` in `modules/network/network.tf` but the azurerm modules are not available to select
[image]

If I try and create those two resources in `modules/cluster/cluster.tf they are available

[image]

and I can write the so:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
    tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
    Team = "DevOps"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "server_cluster" {
...
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public-ip" {
  name                = "PublicIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "load-balancer" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.public-ip.id
  }
}
```

Why aren't the providers available in `network.tf`?
Shouldn't they be available in the network module as they are in the cluster module?
From the docs network module should inherit the azurerm provider from main.tf

> If not specified, the child >module inherits all of the >default (un-aliased) provider >configurations from the calling >module.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: "but the provider's modules are not available" it is unclear what this means.

Comment: Could you please share what exactly is the issue?
- "but the provider's modules are not available"
- "tweaking it to finally deploy a server in the cluster and I got stuck with it."

By server do you mean kubrrnetes  kind components like pod, deployment etc etc. 
Please clarify

Comment: yeah you're right. let me try to explain myself better and update the question

Comment: hope it's more clear now. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Vincenzo so you are basically complaining about the terraform extension in VScode not working? :)

Comment: @MarkoE, no I'm not complaining about that,  I'm new to Terraform and  I'm asking why I'm experiencing a certain unexpected behaviour. If Terraform extension is the problem is good to know it and thanks for pointing it out. If  instead i'm writing bad code because I'm just learning it then the help from experienced devs is much needed. Sarcasm has never helped anybody. ;)

Comment: So you think it is just the extension that is not working?

Comment: No, I was genuinely asking if that was the issue. Because if there are no errors, I thought that the extension was the thing bothering you.

Comment: As for the providers, if it is an official terraform provider (which kubernetes and azure are), you shouldn't need to specify it on the child module level, only in the root module. More information here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#implicit-provider-inheritance

Comment: Yeap.. that's the problem. Some how only the cluster child module gets the azure provider. The network child module doesn't get any provider , azure or kubernetes. That's why i'm asking for help. Maybe some misconfiguration ?

Comment: You appear to be relying on the VS Code Terrraform extension to tell  you what is "available" in that module. If you manually type in the value there do you get any errors when you run `terraform plan`? Because it looks like that VS Code extension is simply not working right.

Comment: yes you're right, I'm in fact going to run the code and see if terraform throws any error. thanks for pointing that out too

Comment: @MarkoE as I commented on the answer from Swarna Anipindi I started a new project and in any module.tf file the extension doesn't show any autocomplete (for providers' modules) for the first resource I add, but then for the second resource it kinda picks up and start showing autocomplete hints again.. did you experience this behaviour?

Comment: I added some configuration into settings which did help a bit, but I do experience odd behaviour from time to time.

Comment: Could you share what setting did you edit?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to replicate the same scenario using below mentioned [code](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb). Everything is working as expected.  Hope issue may cause because of module declaration.

Main tf code as follows:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
    host                   =  module.cluster.host
    client_certificate     =  module.cluster.client_certificate
    client_key             =  module.cluster.client_key
    cluster_ca_certificate =  module.cluster.cluster_ca_certificate
}

module "cluster" {
  source = "./modules/cluster"
}
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  
}
```

NOTE: No more parameters require on provider tf file. Just declaration of module is sufficient.

Provider tf file as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
```

Cluster file as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "swarnaexample-aks1"
  location            = "East Us"
  resource_group_name =  "*********"
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.client_certificate
  sensitive = true
}

output "kube_config" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config_raw

  sensitive = true
}
```

network tf file as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "***********"
  location = "East Us"
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "swarnapIPForLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "swarnaLB"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPadd"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}
```

from the code
[image]

Upon running of plan and apply

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I'm testing it right now and indeed the problem I had seems to be related with the extension not working properly as @Marko E pointed out. I started a new project and in any module.tf file the extension doesn't show any autocomplete (for providers' modules) for the first resource I add, but then it kinda picks up and start showing autocomplete hints again.. What extension do you have on? can you confirm mi findings creating a new module and see if for the first resource you add tho the file you get autocomplete hints for the azurerm provider? many thanks

Comment: I don't believe so; there's a problem with the extension. I have consumed the same extensions that we used in the above code base mentioned in the thread. Few changes i made is declared all modules in main.tf and removed unnecessary syntax from there.  Try with above code once, happy to help if any further issues.

Comment: It all works, but still it bugs me that the extension does not work right away but only from the second resource declaration onward.. weird but hey I'll dig into it and see what I find out. I did install the HashiCorp Terraform and the Microsoft's Azure Terraform after the issue but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: upgrade latest Extension "Azure Terraform" v0.3.2 and Azure CLI Tools in VSCode and try once again.